# Forgotten to print boarding pass for return flight via Thomson

Tags: airports, thomson-airways

I forgot to print off my boarding pass before I got to the airport can I just print this off on the way back while on holiday (perhaps at the hotel)

Comment: What is the question here? I don't see why you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, a boarding pass is stored electronically.

As such, it can be printed anywhere there is a terminal that "links" to the airline system. Any travel agency will have such a (Thomson) terminal, and probably most hotels.